# Tornado memory leaks

Tags: python, memory-leaks, tornado

We develop the application that use Tornado(2.4) and tornadio2 for transport. We have a problem with memory leaks, and tried to find what is wrong with pympler, but it haven't catched any leaks. But the problem is. Pmap shows us that memory is  used (look through the added with the link screenshot http://prntscr.com/16wv6k). 
There are more then 90% of memory is used by one anon process. 
Whith every user coming in our application reserve some memory, but with user out memory is still reserved and doesnt free. We can't understand what is the problem.

The question is - what should we do to remove this leaks? We have to rebot server every hour just for 500 user online. It's bad((

Comment: Your "memory leak" might actually be [memory fragmentation](http://revista.python.org.ar/2/en/html/memory-fragmentation.html).

Comment: This 'question' is way to vague. Please specify what you have tried so far to analyze the problem, what you are doing with Tornado. And don't forget to clarify what your question is ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this (already closed) bug ?

https://github.com/facebook/tornado/commit/bff07405549a6eb173a4cfc9bbc3fc7c6da5cdd7